# How to view a GRF file

Tags: zpl

I have a txt file which is an impression of ZPL, but I can't preview that file. When opening the txt it has the following markup:

```
# ~DGR:DEMO.GRF,124236,102,:Z64:
```

What tool or code can I use to view this file?

Comment: `What tool` - http://labelary.com/viewer.html.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to put the file on that site the way you said but it didn't work. I used this [Link](http://labelary.com/viewer.html) to be able to view the file.

Answer (score -1):

The compression used for the GRF file is base64, so if you copy [here](https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter) all the stuff after the "Z64:" , you should be able to see the image.

Comment: I tried to put the file on that site the way you said but it didn't work. I used this [Link](http://labelary.com/viewer.html) to be able to view the file. Thanks for replying.